# Azure SDK 2.7 standalone installer

Tags: azure, azure-sdk-.net

The Azure SDK 2.7 download is over 300MB.  We have a large team of developers needing to do the update.

Is there no available standalone installer for this?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can manually download current SDK (2.7) from here: http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=48178.

You may also find this link helpful in downloading current and old SDKs: http://azure.microsoft.com/en-in/downloads/archive-net-downloads/.

Comment: I'm looking for 2.7 and it looks like only 2.7.1 is available.  Any ideas how to get 2.7?

Answer (score 3):

Web Platform Installer downloads the SDKs/Msi here C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\installers on a windows machine and the feed here C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\preprocessor

Once downloaded completely you can upload the installers to local repository and modify the feed to pick the installers from local repositories than downloading from internet by using the options menu in the Web Platform Installer. Let me know if this works for you.

You can also look at the logs (C:\Users[UserName]\AppData\Local\Microsoft\Web Platform Installer\logs) for more information on how to customize.